# Understanding firebase firestore indexes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After reading through the firestore documentation about indexing I want to confirm that this is how a single-field index would look like:
Let's say I have a firestore collection cars with following documents:

```
car123: {
    brand:"Mercedes"
    model:"W123",
    },
car423: {
    brand:"BMW",
    model:"x5"
    },
carXyZ: {
    brand:"Mercedes",
    model:"S 500"
}
```

Would the indices that firestore creates automatically really look something more or less like this?

```
index for queries filtering by brand equals "Mercedes" = ["car123", "carXyZ"]
index for queries filtering by brand equals "BMW" = ["car423"]
index for queries filtering model equals "S 500" = ["CarXyZ"]
```

..and does this mean each time a car is added n indices are updated whereas n is the number of keys that car has + of each index one ASC and one DESC version?

Answer (score 1):

The examples provided by you are an oversimplification of the what an actual index looks like, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/index-overview#single-field_indexes):

> A single-field index stores a sorted mapping of all the documents in a
> collection that contain a specific field. Each entry in a single-field
> index records a document's value for a specific field and the location
> of the document in the database.

So according to the excerpt cited, an index at least has 4 things, a mapping with all the documents that have the single-field index, the single field index, the value of that index per document and the location of the document in the database, how that structure looks like is not provided publicly as far as I know.

Regarding your question, it's possible to infer, that each time a new document, with a field that is being part of a single-field index, is created, it will be added to two single field-index structures the Descending and Ascending one.